# In LinqPad, querying Databases in LinqPad 6 and 7

Tags: linqpad, sysobjects

In LinqPad 5 the following code example works very well for accessing information for databases which includes information such as Recovery Model, encryption status and other useful information for a DBA.  This is using **Linq to SQL** for the SQL Server Database connection.

```
from d in Databases
select d
```

**when database connection in LINQPad points to the master database for a SQL server.*

However, access to **Databases** does not work in LinqPad 6 or 7.  I have been trying for a while to upgrade my queries that use Databases so I can run them in LinqPad 6+ without success.

Is there any setting that can be used or an alternate query to accomplish the same results in LinqPad 6 and 7?

Comment: What does your connection connect to? I don't have a `Databases` object in my LINQ to SQL connection to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

If you tick **Include System Tables, Views and SPs** in Connection Properties > Advanced, you'll be able to access `sys.Databases`. Interestingly, this works for every database *except* master (I'll get this fixed in the next LINQPad 7 build).

Note that LINQPad 5 incorrectly exposed this property as `Databases` rather than `sys.Databases`.